# Background Color not stretching to full width on mobile (Next.js)

Tags: css, next.js

[image] I am using Next.js to develop a website. However, when I set a certain background color to the particular component (the light purple color in the image), the color display fully on desktop, but does not stretch fully on mobile. Please I need help.

Here is the CSS code I used in setting the background color. (Check the "hero-home" class selector)

```
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


html,
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
 Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
 
 
}

.hero-home{
background-color: rgba(102, 0, 102, 0.1);
}

a {
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
}

* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more contextual info to understand the problem. Try sharing what you're doing in your code or a reproducible code sandbox demo.

Comment: I have provided my CSS code.

Comment: Do you have a preview URL to inspect the html/css? You can host freely on vercel.

Comment: I think i have found a way around it. I had to change the initial scale of the viewport meta tag in the _app.js